# Implementing push notifications from WCF webservice

Tags: c#, ios, wcf, mobile, push-notification

I have been designing an app back-end using WCF web services. The app (iOS initially) will communicate with this webservice to send and receive all the data it needs from the server.

I want to be able to support push notifications as for example when you call the "PlaceOrder" web method, it needs to be able to send a notification to all users who are part of the order and let them know the order has been processed, updated, completed etc, or if you decline payment, it then notifies all other people in the order of this.

I assume push notifications is the best way to do this but I can't seem to find anything about implementing this from a WCF web-service. What I ideally want is to create a notification interface which I can call from my WCF code, letting it know a message body, type and a user token of where to route it. The implementation of that interface would then be the mobile iOS push notification service or Android etc.

Am I barking up the wrong tree or is this the correct way to do it? And does anyone have a link to an example of how to do this in WCF?

Comment: They are implemented the same way in WCF, console and wherever else. Just google for ".net ios push notification".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) :A server-side library for sending Push Notifications to clients (the clients are basically mobile devices - but can be custom as well)! You google to get some tutorial on PushSharp use as well.